# Google Analytics Goals Not Adding Up With Goal Funnel

Tags: analytics, goals

In my Google Analytics, I have a Goal URL defined for an exact match of a "thank you" page. When I view in my reports under Conversion > Funnel Visualization, it says at the bottom of my report that 27 people completed the funnel and saw the "thank you" page. However, when I look at my content report and check for how many unique visitors saw the page, it says 38. It also says 38 when I click "goal flow" under the conversions reports.

Shouldn't the numbers all be the same? Anybody know why it's not?

Answer (score 1):

Basically some people did not complete the funnel and see the thank you page, if should show you the number who dropped out, it could also happen because of an error.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question states that 27 people in "funnel visualization" completed the signup and got to the "thank you" page, whereas in the "goal flow" and content report, it states that 38 people saw the "thank you" page. Guessing this might be an error or bug on GA's fault?

Comment: @TMC The difference is people who saw the thankyou page without going through the funnel.